# Intermittent 102 Error (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED) when connecting to JIRA

Tags: tomcat, networking, jira, http-error, catalina

For the last few months we have suffered from intermittent 102 errors when trying to connect to our internal server hosting JIRA and Stash over port 8080 and 7990 respectively.

I'm not familiar with the Java stack but I believe that when installing JIRA on the machine, it sets up Catalina Tomcat server.

I haven't been able to find any useful logs which indicate any issues. What steps can I take to diagnose this problem?

Comment: You are right, it uses Tomcat server. For further debugging you can check logs in application folder. i.e catalina.out. Would also be helpful on what steps do you take when you have errors

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check your atlassian-jira.log (in the JIRA home folder) and catalina.out (in your JIRA install folder). If you have an apache or other reverse proxy in front of your JIRA you can also check the logfiles there.

For more info about where you can find those logs, check:

- [Where are the application server logs?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/where-are-the-application-server-logs-695240952.html)
- [Logging and profiling](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/logging-and-profiling-861253813.html)